# Function to find number of 'ordered combinations' with no particular length of a list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation

While variants of this question have been asked numerous times on this site, I haven't found any information on how to do 'ordered combinations' with a given list.

First of all, I don't exactly know what the correct term for this function is, but I will use this list:

`list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

What I want to find is how many possible ways this list can be ordered, so that

`list[0] < list[1] < list[2] ... < list[len(list)-1]` (Ascending order w/o repeats )

But

`list[0] + 1` doesn't have to be equal to `list[1]` (Doesn't matter which numbers are chosen, so long that they are in ascending order and are in the list)

And, assuming `outList` is a qualifying list sourced from `list`

`len(outList)` doesn't have to be to `len(list)` -  'Qualifying' lists do not have to be the same length of the given list, but it must not be longer.

Some examples of what would fit under these rules:

[1,4,5,9]
[2,6,7,8,9]
[1,2,4,8]
[8,10]

Some non-examples:

[1,3,2,5,10]
[1,1,10]
[5,2,8,7,9]

Numbers CANNOT repeat, and they must strictly be larger than the previous number.

How would I go about making such a function? I haven't a clue at how to approach such a problem. I tried using a `for` loop, but I couldn't seem to get that to work properly.

Edit: sorry this question was unclear, and if it still is, because I really don't know what term I would use. I didn't know how to phrase it correctly, so I added some more detail, and my version of the answer is down below. Clearly it is not optimized. Btw AlexanderCécile, if you look at my history, I used to do js and jQuery (not that I don't anymore, but I changed my focus), so the function follows the naming standards of js.

Second edit: All these answers are quite different from each other, which shows the beauty of coding :) - My solution is quite basic, although it does work. Do these work quicker on higher length lists, such as [1,2,3,4...100,101]?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutation-and-combination-in-python/

Comment: Permutations normally suggest you will be taking a specific number of elements to construct each group? Do you want all possible group sizes?

Comment: I think I figured it out, but it most likely can be optimized. This also includes a void list, because technically it does follow the rules of my function

Comment: Must each number be strictly larger than the previous one, or could it also be equal?

Comment: You should edit your question to make it clearer that you are looking for the number of possible combinations. I originally thought you wanted a list of sorted combinations until I saw your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to know how many different lists there are with some subset of the elements as `lst`, kept in order. Since each subset can only exist in one order, the answer is simply the [number of subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set): 2^n where n is the length of the list.

```py
def count_subsets(lst):
    return 2 ** len(lst)
```

For example, if the list is `[1, 2, 3]` then there are 2^3 = 8 ordered sublists:

1. `[]`
2. `[1]`
3. `[2]`
4. `[3]`
5. `[1, 2]`
6. `[1, 3]`
7. `[2, 3]`
8. `[1, 2, 3]`

If you want to exclude the empty list and/or the original list, you can simply do `2 ** len(lst) - 1` or `max(0, 2 ** len(lst) - 2)`, as appropriate. The `max(0, ...)` handles the special case when your input list *is* empty.

---

The above handles the case like your example when the elements of the input list are all distinct. If there may be repeated elements, then the formula above overcounts. To fix it, we can use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to find the number of copies of each element. If there are `k` copies of some element, then instead of `2 ** k` combinations, we should count `k + 1` sublists containing 0, 1, 2, ..., k copies.

```py
from collections import Counter

def count_subsets(lst):
    r = 1
    for k in Counter(lst).values():
        r *= k + 1
    return r
```

Comment: What math class is this taught in? I know little about this, since I'm only in precalc at the moment.

Comment: That's different in different places; I wouldn't be able to guess. This is either basic set theory or combinatorics.

Comment: Why did you decide to not use the pow(x,y) function? This speeds up the process considerably for larger sets.

Comment: If you want to use `pow` instead then go ahead; I write `**` because I think it is more readable. My benchmarks show `**` is a bit *faster* than `pow` when the exponent is 100, 1000 or 10000, but this probably depends on which version of Python you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this mathematically using the [formula to calculate the number of combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

```py
import math
def binomial_coeff(n, k):
    return math.factorial(n) // (math.factorial(k) * math.factorial(n - k))

def num_all_combinations(lst_len):
    return sum(binomial_coeff(lst_len, i) for i in range(lst_len))

list1 = list(range(10))
print(num_all_combinations(len(list1))) # prints 1023
```

The `binomial_coeff` function uses the combinations formula (also known as the binomial coefficient) to get the number of combinations for a list of size `n` with groups of size `k`. We then use the `num_all_combinations` function to get the number of combinations for all group sizes and add them together.

You can even simplify this further using the [sums of binomial coefficients identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients) as suggested by @kaya3. This would result in the following code:

```
list1 = list(range(10))
print(2**len(list1) - 1) # prints 1023
```

Comment: Hey if `num_all_combinations` doesn't use any values from `lst`, why not just pass in the length of the list? i.e. `num_all_combinations(len(list1))`

Comment: I originally had a typo in which it looped over the list, but it really just needed the length. I fixed the typo, but forgot to make it so the function didn't take the list as an argument. Good catch, I'll update it.

Comment: This can be hugely simplified using the identity sum_i (n choose i) = 2^n.

Comment: @kaya3 Good catch, I was not aware of that identity. Will adjust my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is most likely unoptimized, but I somehow figured out what I wanted to do. Is there a nice way to improve this?

```
def orderedCombinations():
    z = 0
    for x in range(len(list1)):
        comb = combinations(list1, x)
        for i in list(comb):
            z += 1
    print(str(z))
```

Comment: What is the point of a function which takes no parameters and returns nothing? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: It looks like you might just be interested in the total number of combinations for any group size. If so, that can be calculated mathematically.

Comment: @KieranMoynihan You mean in terms of variable naming?